# every countable dense subset of R can be partitioned into countably many disjoint dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis

we know a countable dense subset of R can be partitioned into finitely many disjoint dense subset.now we try to partition it into countably many dense subset which are disjoint

Comment: Please tell us how you partition a countable dense set into finitely many disjoint dense sets. Then maybe we can see what is stopping us from doing countably many disjoint dense sets the same way.

Comment: from the set of rational to the countable dense subset has a order preserving bijection and we can extended it to homeomorphic function from R to R and as we can partition the rational into finitely many dense subset so we can partition the countable dense subset into finitely many dense subset.but can we partition the rational into countably many disjoint dense subset?

Comment: The same argument works for your question. You can partition the rationals into countably many dense subsets; using the order-preserving homeomorphism you get get a partition of any countable dense set into countably many dense sets.

Comment: How do you partition the rationals into finitely many dense sets?

Answer (score 1):

Any two countable dense sets in R are homeomorphic. Let ${x_1,x_2,...}$ be a sequence of irrationals independent over Q. Multiply Q by these irrationals to get a disjoint sequence of countable dense sets. Their union is homeomorphic to Q. Pull back these countable dense sets into Q. Each of these pullbacks is dense in Q, hence in R. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be a countable dense set. Let $\mathcal I$ be the set of all open intervals with rational endpoints. Since the Cartesian product $\mathcal I\times\mathbb N$ is a countable set, we can list its elements in an infinite sequence:
$$\mathcal I\times\mathbb N=\{\langle I_k,n_k\rangle:k=1,2,3,\dots\}.$$
Construct an infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_k,\dots$ such that $a_k\in D\cap I_k\setminus\{a_j:j\lt k\};$ this is possible because $D\cap I_k\ne\emptyset.$

Finally, for each $n\in\mathbb N,$ define $A_n=\{a_k:n_k=n\}.$ The sets $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint dense subsets of $D,$ and each $A_n$ is dense because $A_n\cap I\ne\emptyset$ for every $I\in\mathcal I.$

Comment: I don't understand the last part. We have to show that $A_n\Cap I_k\ne\emptyset$ for every pair (n,k) and we do not know that $n_k=n$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What we have to show is that $A_n\cap I\ne\emptyset$ for every pair $\langle I,n\rangle\in\mathcal I\times\mathbb N.$ Given $I\in\mathcal I$ and $n\in\mathbb N,$ find $k$ so that $\langle I,n\rangle=\langle I_k,n_k\rangle.$ Then $a_k\in A_n$ because $n_k=n,$ and $a_k\in I_k=I,$ so $a_k\in A_n\cap I.$